# best_in_place error in heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I have the best_in_place gem working in my dev environment, however when I deploy to Heroku, I receive the following error in my view:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `best_in_place' for #<#<Class:0x000000036600a0>:0x000000037a12e8>):
2013-04-05T13:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     56:               <% end %>
2013-04-05T13:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     57:             </div>
2013-04-05T13:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     61:           </div>
2013-04-05T13:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     62:           <div class="budget_description budget_field">
2013-04-05T13:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/budgets_controller.rb:33:in `show'
2013-04-05T13:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-05T13:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     58:             <div class="budget_name budget_workspace">
2013-04-05T13:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     59:               <h1><%= best_in_place @budget, :name, :inner_class => "test" %></h1>
```

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'    
gem 'devise'
gem 'pg'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'best_in_place'
end
```

Does `gem 'best_in_place'` need to be outside the assets group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should move the `best_in_place` gem out of the `assets` group.

The assets group is only included during deployment for asset compilation, not during run time.